# Rewritten URL and AJAX

Tags: ajax, url, url-rewriting

I wonder if it is possible to make work ajax with rewritten urls. For instance I have a php file named receiving a post method call from a javascript :"ajaxfile.php" and has been rewritten to "/rewritten-url/".

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
         $.post("/rewritten-url/", {parameter: "75"}, function(result){
            $("#canvas").html(result);
         });
     });
 });
```

There is a way to keep the call towards "/rewritten-url/" or have I to keep the call to "ajaxfile.php"? I tried a small example and it works fine with "ajaxfile.php" but not with "/rewritten-url/".

If you ask me "why would I like to do this?" It is just curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, ajax requests are the same as normal browser requests, they transfer over http so you can rewrite, redirect, etc.

If you are using apache, you can use the [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to do this just like you would do with a normal php file.